# Python Xpath to find text() that contains @domain

Tags: python, xpath

I'm looking for the right xpath expression to search all text() in html page that contains the string: @domain

on a match extract till the first space on the left and till the first space on the right -

just to fetch the email address.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Xpath query will fetch text of all nodes containing '@domain'

```
//*[contains(text(), '@domain')]/text()
```

You can then parse the text to extract the email using Python

```
>>> import re
>>> re.findall(r'[\w\.]+@domain\.[\w\.]+', 'this is our info: info@domain.co.uk')
['info@domain.co.uk']
```

UPDATE:

Looks like XPath selectors in scrapy [have `re` method](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html#using-selectors-with-regular-expressions), which i wasn't aware of:

```
>>> hxs.select('//a[contains(@href, "image")]/text()').re(r'Name:\s*(.*)')
[u'My image 1',
 u'My image 2',
 u'My image 3',
 u'My image 4',
 u'My image 5']
```

Comment: Could you please help me out with the regular expression to meet my conditions?

for example if this string was extracted: "this is our info: info@domain.co.uk
the result should be only info@domain.co.uk

Comment: I've added an example for regex. It's too simple, so you might want to learn regex and improve it. There are many examples on stackoverflow for email address regexes.

Comment: thanks!
Is there a reason you used findall? (just to find all emails?)

Comment: findall returns tuple of strings found, while other re functions return match objects. I used findall for demo purpose of a working regex

Comment: Thanks, I will be using it like:
select("//*[contains(text(), '@domain')]/text()").re(r'[\w\.]+@domain\.[\w\.]+')

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14664/discussion-between-user1537701-and-warwaruk)